# HTML pixel Game

Tags: javascript, html, pixel

I am making a 64x64 monochrome pixel game for web. What is the most efficient method for rendering the zoomed image of the game on web-page in HTML5/JavaScript without using extra libraries?

Comment: Canvas is what you are looking for

Comment: For that I would recommend phaser.io or pixi.js, those libraries work on top of the canvas and use webgl acceleration if available

Comment: @philipp : OP asked "without using extra libraries"

Comment: See this post for how I made my pixel game more optimal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964775/html5-rendering-pixels-to-image-on-load-for-faster-draw-times

Answer (score 1):

If you use only 2 dimensions, Canvas html element is the way to go, with a 2d context. You can draw images on it, lines etc... If you need 3 dimensional support, you can use WebGL on this canvas. This [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) teach you how to use a basic canvas with HTML5 and Javascript, and to manipulate images. For 3D rendering, you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL) MDN tutorial.